# Extract iframe data using ms access vba "object does not support property or method" error

Tags: vba, web-scraping, iframe

During exectuion of below mentioned code,following error appears."Object does not support this property of Method".Any suggestion why my statement does not work?

I appreciate your replies!

```
    Sub Getdata()
 Dim Ie As New InternetExplorer
 Dim WebURL
 Dim Docx As HTMLDocument
 Dim productDesc1
 Dim productTitle
 Dim price
 Dim RcdNum
Ie.Visible = False
    WebURL = "http://www.amazon.com/Pyramex-I-Force-Sporty-Anti-Fog-Goggle/dp/B006WPSDXS/ref=sr_1_1?s=sporting-goods&ie=UTF8&qid=1455101600&sr=1-1&keywords=glassess"
     Ie.Navigate2 WebURL
     Do Until Ie.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
     DoEvents
     Loop
     Set Docx = Ie.Document

     productDesc1 = Docx.window.frames("product-description-iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementsByClassName("productDescriptionWrapper").innerText



End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please go through the tour and the faq before asking questions. Your question is also in need of editing. The code is all in one line.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName("productDescriptionWrapper")` will return a *collection* of elements (even if there's only one found).

That collection deosn't have an `innerText` property - you need to use something like:

```
 productDesc1 = Docx.frames("product-description-iframe"). _
                   document.getElementsByClassName( _
                   "productDescriptionWrapper")(0).innerText
```

**EDIT**: made some changes - tested and works for me

Comment: I use above method but still error is same i.e Object does not support this property or method,Please note that i am using MS Access VBA.